# ldd shows a set of libraries linked in, but using rabin2 -l shows differently. Why is that so?

Tags: dynamic-linking

While trying to debug something, i noticed that `ldd <executable>` would show a bunch of libraries like `libldap_r`, `libkrb5` and `libroken`, amongst others. On the other hand a `rabin2 -l <executable>` does not show the same set of libraries.

I've grepped through the source directory for ldap strings from linking or function calls but they don't show up, implying that these libraries shouldn't be linked in anyway. What should i do to find out if the libraries are being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rabin2 -l` shows a binary’s direct dependencies, *i.e.* those that are listed in the binary itself. `ldd` shows a binary’s fully-resolved dependency tree (as far as possible); this includes transitive dependencies. Thus if a binary needs `liba` and `libb`, and `liba` needs `libd` which itself needs `libe`, `rabin2 -l` will only list `liba` and `libb`, whereas `ldd` will show all four libraries (if they are all available).

You can match `ldd`’s result manually using `rabin2 -l` by listing the first binary’s dependencies, then each individual dependency’s dependencies, and so on until no new dependency is identified.

To find out if a library is actually being used, you can the binary with `ltrace` in all the scenarios you care about. This will identify the library functions that are called. Note that the use of certain libraries will be configuration-dependent; for example the Kerberos libraries would presumably only be used if Kerberos is configured.

See also [ldd vs rpm -q --requires](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628814/86440).

Comment: Guess everything needs `libc`

Comment: I skipped it to avoid confusion ;-).

Comment: Great! I thought so, but didn't find any answers to this question when searching the web.